# Click function raw javascript

Tags: javascript

Javascript

```
function click() {
    var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
        'view': window,
        'bubbles': true,
        'cancelable': true
    });

    document.getElementById('a').dispatchEvent(event);
    document.getElementById('b').dispatchEvent(event);
    document.getElementById('c').dispatchEvent(event);
}
var recycle = setInterval(click, 500);
```

HTML

```
<button id="a">click</button>
<button id="b">click</button>
<button id="c">click</button>
```

My current function is having issues with the MouseEvent.

I want this javascript to be able to cycle through clicking a, b, and c. This seems to only trigger a click for the first instance. What modifications do I need to make?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this but I think the issue stems from the fact that you're trying to use one event object three times. You may have to recreate that object for each dispatch.

Comment: What is a better method than recreating it to avoid redundancy? (I don't want to use jQuery)

Comment: @OP: recreating it does not necessarily mean redundancy.

Comment: It works http://jsbin.com/zinisufaco/1/edit

Comment: It has nothing to do with the single event object because they are bound to different elements.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033315/reusable-javascript-event-object